# browser can't find file for background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, github-pages

I'm trying to use local files for my background image, and it works when I preview it through my text editor, but when I push the changes to my github page the console returns `GET http://davez01d.github.io/images/background-1.PNG 404 (Not Found)`. Here's the script for loading background images -

```
var backgroundImages = [
    {url: '../images/background-1.PNG', credit: 'http://www.intrawallpaper.com'},
    {url: '../images/background-2.JPG', credit: 'David Stewart'},
    {url: '../images/background-3.JPG', credit: 'David Stewart'},
    {url: '../images/background-4.GIF', credit: 'http://jecichon.tumblr.com'},
  ];

  $('#hero').css('background-image', 'url(' + backgroundImages[Math.floor(Math.random()*backgroundImages.length)].url + ')');
```

and my file structure is set up like this

```
-Davez01d.github.io
  -css
    -style.css
   -images
     -background-1.PNG
     -background-2.JPG
     -etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension of files you have on your github are with lower case. Replace PNG, JPG, GIF with png, jpg, gif and it works.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!